# initialise variable using or operator

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation

I want to initialise a variable with the contents of another variable, or a predefined value, if said other variable is not set.

I know I could use

```
if(isset($var1)){
    $var2 = $var1;
} else{
    $var2 = "predefined value";
}
```

I thought doing it like this would be more elegant:

```
$var2 = $var1 || "predefined value";
```

Last time I checked, this did work (or my memory is fooling me). But here, when I print $var2, it is always `1`. It seems PHP checks if the statement `$var1 || "predefined value"` is true and assigns `1` to `$var2`.

**I want "predefined value" to be assigned to $var2, in case $var1 doesn't exist.**
Any peculiarity of PHP I'm missing here to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use $var2 = isset($var1) ? $var1 : "predefined value";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally create a helper function like this:

```
function issetor(&$var, $def = false) {
    return isset($var) ? $var : $def;
}
```

and call it with the reference of the variable :

```
$var2 = issetor($var1, "predefined");
```

Comment: I take that a version with just the `||` param doesn't work as expected in PHP. I may have mixed up my previous results with a Javascript execution

Comment: || is a logical operation and the expression (a || b) will always return 0 or 1.  That is the reason you are getting 1 here.

Comment: It does however work in javascript that way. (go through the statement (var a = a || b || c) until you find a value that's not falsey, and finally assign said value).

Answer (score 0):

I just read that in **PHP 7**, there will be a new abbreviation for

```
$c = ($a === NULL) ? $b : $a;
```

It will look like this:

```
$c = $a ?? $b;
```

And can be extended like this:

```
$c = $a ?? $b ?? $c ?? $d;
```

explanation: $c will be assigned the first value from the left, which is not NULL.